# How to icecast a merged incoming icecast audio stream with local webcam?

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, icecast

I have my webcam attached via usb to a server running ubuntu with icecast, webcamoid and ffmpeg. Then I have a laptop broadcasting the audio to the server.
I have tried with a mix of icecast (also via liquidsoap) and ffmpeg bash scripts, but I am not able to access a merged video.
I'm sure there must be some common/best practice to even a simple setup like this, but it's confusing to me which of them does what.
Is icecast able to do do it by itself or with relaying? or is ffmpeg supposed to merge everything? or is it a combination of the two?